# mongoid having multiple owners for an element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a model for User and a model for Article.
So in the article model I want to have an owner, and a reviewer (2 different users).
Owner is easy - belongs_to :owner.
But what about reviewer?
Do I need to have an Integer field with the id of the reviewer document?
Do I use belongs_to again?

I'm a bit confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `inverse_of` keyword:

```
class User
  has_many :articles,   class_name: 'Article', inverse_of: :owner
  has_many :reviews,    class_name: 'Article', inverse_of: :reviewer
end

class Article
  belongs_to :owner,    class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :articles
  belongs_to :reviewer, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :reviews
end
```

This will tell mongoid what is the "inverse" relation name for you association.